# Get ContentChild of vewRef.createComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We are making a library, and in the library there is a panel, in the panel there are three components: `panel`, `panel-body`, and `panel-footer`.

The user using our library uses two of the components `panel-body` and `panel-footer`. They open the panel using a service like this: `this.panelService.open(MyCustomPanel)`. Which then creates a `panel` component, and injects their component `@Inject(COMP)` into the `panel` component.

In the `panel` component, I create the users injected component and place it in the div, which works just fine. The problem I am having is getting a reference to the `panel-footer`. I want to grab it, and move it to the one in the `#footer` of the library's component.

**panel.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div #body></div>
    <div #footer></div>
  `
})
export class Panel<T> {
  @ContentChild(PanelFooter, { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef, descendants: true })
  protected userFooter!: ViewContainerRef;


  @ViewChild('body', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  protected body!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(@Inject(COMP) private component) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.body.createComponent<T>(this.component, /* injector */);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Displays 'undefined'
    console.log(this.userFooter);
  }
}
```

**my-custom-panel.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <panel-body>
      <!-- some input fields -->
    </panel-body>

    <!-- I want this component: -->
    <panel-footer>
      <button>Action</button>
    </panel-footer>
  `
})
export class MyCustomPanel {}
```